# rename an html page according to an image within it

Tags: html, database, file-rename

firstly I'll give some background regarding the situation.
I have a website containing approximately 56k pages each page contain a mapped sketch of a machine part. this machine part is made out of smaller parts which are outlined in the image and hold a certain number. when you hover over the numbers a box with the part item code shows up.

I order parts according to this item codes but recently a lot of the items codes have changed, therefore I am looking for a solution.

now I own a database with data on all the 56k parts and I want to link the relevant webpage to each record according to the name of the part(a column in my database), the problem is that the webpages names has no logic name that could connect with the part name in any way but the image that is displayed in the page has the exact name of the part.

I want to rename all the html files I has according to the Images displayed within them. how can I achieve that without renaming all the 56k pages manually?

additionally how can I add the links to all the 56k pages automatically to my database after all the above is done?

Thank you for your patience I know it was long.

Comment: Is the part name unique? Unless you can guarantee that each part has a globally unique name, it shouldn't be used as the filename for the page representing that part. In that case, you should use the parts table's primary key (an auto incrementing int?) instead.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to scan the directory of the web server for html files, and for each file extract the image name and the url it points to, to build a correspondence table between image names and old html file names?

Comment: Yes each part name is unique.(it isn't exactly a name but more of a code itself. eg. E106)                                              "If I understand correctly you want to scan the directory of the web server for html files, and for each file extract the image name and the url it points to, to build a correspondence table between image names and old html file names? – mplungjan" exactly

Comment: You must do that with JS? You can't really do that with JS, so can't you use something else server-side, like PHP?

Comment: @DanMan no it doesn't have to be with JS I'm only looking for a simple solution a noobie like me could understand and implement. and since I have some background with JS I thought maybe it will be possible to use it for this kind of task.

Comment: Well, which languages do you know then? Kinda pointless to write something up, and then you don't know the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a *nix shell, then a simple `egrep` will get you far

```
egrep "<img src=\".*\"" -r . > list
```

The regexp would have to be adapted to match the part you are looking for of course.

You could easily to some search/replace in the resulting list to create a batch script that will do all the renaming for you.

Comment: could you please elaborate on this? what is "nix shell", "egrep" and "regexp"? how exactly will it be implemented in a script?

Comment: *nix is short for unix, linux etc where the shell is the layer between you and the machine. egrep is a tool that searches files for Regular Expressions (patterns of characters), regexp is short for Regular Expression and is a concept more than a specific tool. 

I'm thinking that maybe you should get someone more experienced to take a look at this problem as it will save you a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Pick your favorite scripting language and parse each html file to find the image name to use in renaming the file. Personally I would use Perl as it makes parsing the files and updating a database at the same time with the URL *easy*.

Comment: could you give me some examples please? I'm kinda puzzled with this... please bear in mind that I don't have much experience with programing

Comment: Basically, you can write a program to automate the task you described having to perform manually. This program can be written in any language or using any tool to read each html file, rename it based on the image link found, and update the database with a reference to the URL of the html. Your lack of programming experience sounds like it's a non-starter as any "quick" script requires knowledge of the scripting language itself.